# Combine english and chinese fonts in 1 paragraph style

Tags: fonts, character-styles

When formatting in Chinese text, I 'm wondering if you can create a paragraph style so the Chinese is set in 1 Chinese font, while the numbers are set in English font. So you don't need to highlight and change each number individually in the English font when applying different styles.

Comment: Would be useful to mention which software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have some CN text content which includes some numbers which you need to typeset in another font. In which case you need to create a GREP style linked inside your CN paragraph style, to apply this other font for all the numbers. This, assuming your are using InDesign.

Comment: OK let me try GREP, does this work for all eng text

Answer (score -1):

In InDesign, set the base Paragraph Style as you want, then use Character Style to swap the font of the desired characters.

Comment: "So you don't need to highlight and change each number individually" -- what you describe *is* the full manual way.

Comment: I want the chinese in one chinese font style and the english and numbers within the chinese text to be set at english font because chinese fonts for english looks  awful, if you do lots of chinese formatting

Comment: @usr2564301 you can easily select all numbers from a text/selection/block document, from the "find" menu, then apply a Character Style to the selection. One that's done there's nothing full manual. That's 5 clicks max...